# Is Tithonia diversifolia (mexican sunflower) a nitrogen fixer?

Tags: sunflowers, nitrogen, permaculture

Does [Tithonia diversifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithonia_diversifolia) (aka "Mexican Sunflower") have a symbiotic relationship with [diazotrophs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diazotroph) that fix nitrogen in the soil from the nitrogen in the air?

Mexican Sunflower is *not* a legume, but I've read on some websites that they can increase the nitrogen in the soil. But I've been unable to find a credible source of information stating that diversifolia has a symbiotic relationship with diazotrophs.

I *have* read that Mexican Sunflower is a nutrient accumulator. Does that mean that they just accumulate nitrogen from other nitrogen fixers? Or do they actually fix nitrogen?

Is Tithonia diversifolia (Mexican sunflower) a nitrogen fixer?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know none of the Asteraceae family can fix nitrogen.  However, I found this -

> As a representative of rapid growth Asteraceae plant, M. micrantha, its metabolites can increase the availability of nitrogen by enriching the microbes that participate  in nitrogen cycling pathways.

From [Comparative genomics reveals a unique nitrogen-carbon balance system in Asteraceae](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-40002-9)

This may or may not apply to `Tithonia diversifolia`.  Perhaps it applies to all the Daisy family of plants.